# Angular-hint not working

Tags: angularjs

I have used ng-hint in below code, but it not showing any Angular Hint warning/error  .

Below is my code, here I have used $scope without injecting it

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myapp" ng-hint-include="controller">
 <head>
 <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="hint.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="HelloController" >
   <h2>Hello {{helloTo.title}} !</h2>
  </div>
  <script>
   angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("HelloController", function() {
      $scope.helloTo = {};
      $scope.helloTo.title = "World, AngularJS";
    } );
  </script>
```

Comment: `C:\Users\kantip\Downloads\angular-hint-master\dist\hint.js` is not going to work. Use local webserver.

Comment: This is just demo app, so I havn't used any server, And AngularJS can work without webserver than Angular-hint should also work.

Comment: @Kanti use a relative path, eg. `dist\hint.js`, and make sure that this is the correct path relative to your html.

Comment: @wvdz problem is not with path, hint.js file is loaded but it not showing me any angular hint message and I have also changed path to same directory.

Comment: issue resolved using ngHint.js from testapp of protractor npm package